# How do I deserialize this JSON type

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "results": {
        "exchange": [
            "site.com",
            {
                "currency": "usd",
                "last_traded": "2015.24"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How do I get the `last_traded` value?

I wrote some POJO for this, but I can't seem to find a way to get the key-value inside `exchange` array.

```
public class ExchangeContainer {

    @Expose
    private Results results;

    public Results getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(Results results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }

}

public class Results {

    @Expose
    private List<String> exchange = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getExchange() {
        return exchange;
    }

    public void setExchange(List<String> exchange) {
        this.exchange = exchange;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }
}
```

I'm using GSON to deserialize this JSON.

So in order for me to traverse through the model is:

```
ExchangeContainer response;

String rate = response.getResults().getExchange().get(1); // how to continue?
```

and I'm stuck.

Comment: Shouldn't exchange be a List of Map?

Answer (score 0):

Implement interface using `implements JsonDeserializer` in your class

and override `deserialize` method.

Example link - http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/

Answer (score 0):

As you have **created list of Strings** by

```
private List<String> exchange = new ArrayList<String>();
```

& **setting another list in created list** i.e., in exchange

```
public void setExchange(List<String> exchange)
```

When you get value by invoking line

```
String rate = response.getResults().getExchange().get(1);
```

it contains `"last_traded": "2015.24"` is it right ?

Now **to get** `2015.24`, you have following choices :-

1. **String[] split(":")**
2. **String substring(int beginIndex)**

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Is your problem solved with this answer or you want something else ?